# Generic trait for all containers implementing iter()

Tags: rust

I'm trying to implement a trait for all containers that implement iter(), ie. for all containers that provide an `IntoIterator<Item=&'a T>`. I've tried this, but unfortunately, even for the simplest case it is failing. Maybe someone knows what I'm doing wrong?

```
trait Monotonic<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized> {
    fn is_monotonic(&mut self) -> bool {
    return true;
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized, C> Monotonic<'a, T> for C
where C: IntoIterator<Item=&'a T> + ?Sized {}


fn main() {
    let v = vec![1u32, 2u32, 3u32];
    if v.is_monotonic() {
    print!("Is monotonic!");
    }
}
```

The compiler complains about not satisfied bounds:

```
error[E0599]: the method `is_monotonic` exists for struct `Vec<u32>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
  --> src/test.rs:13:10
   |
13 |     if v.is_monotonic() {
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^ method cannot be called on `Vec<u32>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
  --> /rustc/fc594f15669680fa70d255faec3ca3fb507c3405/library/alloc/src/vec/mod.rs:400:1
   |
   |   = note: doesn't satisfy `<Vec<u32> as IntoIterator>::Item = &_`
  
 = note: doesn't satisfy `Vec<u32>: Monotonic<'_, _>`
   |
note: trait bound `[u32]: IntoIterator` was not satisfied
  --> src/test.rs:8:10
   |
7  | impl<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized, C> Monotonic<'a, T> for C
   |                             ----------------     -
8  | where C: IntoIterator<Item=&'a T> + ?Sized {}
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here
note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
      `<Vec<u32> as IntoIterator>::Item = &_`
      `<[u32] as IntoIterator>::Item = &_`
  --> src/test.rs:8:23
   |
7  | impl<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized, C> Monotonic<'a, T> for C
   |                             ----------------     -
8  | where C: IntoIterator<Item=&'a T> + ?Sized {}
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^ unsatisfied trait bound introduced here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0599`.
```

I've already tried to solve this on my own, but after several attempts I'm at a point where some help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [its documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html), `Vec<T>` implements the following `IntoIterator` traits:

- `IntoIterator<Item = &'a T> for &'a Vec<T, A>`
- `IntoIterator<Item = &'a mut T> for &'a mut Vec<T, A>`
- `IntoIterator<Item = T> for Vec<T, A>`

The variable `v` you are calling it on is a `Vec<u32>`, which only implements `IntoIterator<Item = u32>`, and **not** any kind of `&'a u32` as your trait requires.

There are a couple of solutions. The first one is to run the code on `&v`:

```rust
trait Monotonic<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized> {
    fn is_monotonic(&mut self) -> bool {
        return true;
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized, C> Monotonic<'a, T> for C where C: IntoIterator<Item = &'a T> + ?Sized {}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1u32, 2u32, 3u32];
    if (&v).is_monotonic() {
        print!("Is monotonic!");
    }
}
```

Although that's probably not what you want, because I read from your question that you want your `Monotonic` trait to be implemented as generically as possible. For that, simply remove the `&` requirement:

```rust
trait Monotonic<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized> {
    fn is_monotonic(&mut self) -> bool {
        return true;
    }
}

impl<'a, T: 'a + ?Sized, C> Monotonic<'a, T> for C where C: IntoIterator<Item = T> + ?Sized {}

fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1u32, 2u32, 3u32];
    if v.is_monotonic() {
        print!("Is monotonic!");
    }
}
```

---

Couple of remarks concerning your current code structure, though:

- While this technically compiles, it won't be possible to implement your function. `IntoIterator` **consumes** the object you call it on, but your `is_monotonic` function only has `&mut` access to it, so you won't ever be able to call `into_iter` here.

  What you probably want instead is to have `is_monotonic` **consume** the value, but then only implement it for `&T`.
- Your `Monotonic` function doesn't require any generic parameters, so remove them.

```rust
trait Monotonic {
    fn is_monotonic(self) -> bool;
}

impl<'a, T, C> Monotonic for &'a C
where
    &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
{
    fn is_monotonic(self) -> bool {
        let mut iter = self.into_iter();

        // Do something with iter
        let x = iter.next().unwrap();

        // Return result
        true
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1u32, 2u32, 3u32];
    if v.is_monotonic() {
        print!("Is monotonic!");
    }
}
```

---

Here is an example implementation of `is_monotonic`, assuming it means monotonic rising:

```rust
trait Monotonic {
    fn is_monotonic(self) -> bool;
}

impl<'a, T, C> Monotonic for &'a C
where
    &'a C: IntoIterator<Item = T>,
    T: PartialOrd,
{
    fn is_monotonic(self) -> bool {
        let mut iter = self.into_iter();

        if let Some(first) = iter.next() {
            let mut previous = first;
            for next in iter {
                if !next.ge(&previous) {
                    return false;
                }
                previous = next;
            }
            true
        } else {
            // An iterator without elements is monotonic.
            // Although that's probably up for philosophical debate.
            true
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1u32, 2u32, 3u32];
    if v.is_monotonic() {
        println!("Is monotonic!");
    }
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

```
Is monotonic!
[1, 2, 3]
```